# Why does my simple wpf C# app with a DispatcherTimer appear to leak memory?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a simple wpf C# with a single text box and  DispatcherTimer that displays the result of a call to GC.GetTotalMemory(true) every second. The value returned increases steadily with each call, and task manager shows that the private working memory set increases also.
Is this really a memory leak, or just the appearance of one? In my real app that does a lot more within each tick the memory leakages appear significantly higher.
My code is as follows

**xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPFApplication.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="memoryuseage"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**xaml.cs**

```
namespace TestWPFApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer tmr;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tmr = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            tmr.Interval = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(StaticTick);
            tmr.Start();
        }

        void StaticTick(object o, EventArgs sender)
        {
            memoryuseage.Text = GC.GetTotalMemory(true).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `WeakEventManager` instead of `EventHandler`. ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/weak-event-patterns?view=netdesktop-7.0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this really a memory leak, or just the appearance of one?

Just the appearance. A steady increase is normal, it isn't a leak until you can crash it by running it long enough. But that could take days with a small leak.

Your memory usage ought to level off, but only after a considerable time. You might be able to speed that up by using GC.Collect() here (every 10th tick or so).

For a serious diagnosis you will need a memory-profiler.

For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLR_Profiler

Comment: CLR_Profiler tells me I have 1.7M allocated and task manager tells me I have 127M. Do you know if CLR_Profiler has the ability to dump allocation data to a file?

Comment: This *is* a memory leak caused by the event handler that is called by the timer. WPF timers use low-level system or OS timers which are unmanaged (that's why they implement `IDisposable`). This unmanaged system resource is kept alive until the disposal of the referencing timer object. Because it is an unmanaged system resource, timer resources are not freed even when the application closes. That's why you *must* unsubscribe from the timer events (and even dispose the instance of some timers).

Comment: _"Because it is an unmanaged system resource, timer resources are not freed even when the application closes"_ is total nonsense. And the timer is still a _managed_ resource, even when it uses somnething unmanaged.

Comment: @ℍℍ No, I'm sorry to say that but you are wrong (saying it in a kind way, d'you like it?). Of course, the timer itself is managed. That's why you don't have to free it explicitly and it gets garbage collected. However, the timer itself allocates unmanaged resources. And implements a special behavior in terms of resource management: it keeps this resources alive until the timer instance itself has no more event subscribers. Even the docs clearly state : *"A DispatcherTimer will keep an object alive whenever the object's methods are bound to the timer."*. The profiler is proofing the same.

Comment: @ℍℍ It's just how WPF manages its timers. See my answer. I have posted the memory profiler results. They prove that your statements are all wrong.

Comment: _"WPF timers use low-level system or OS timers which are unmanaged (that's why they implement IDisposable)."_ is all false. And that's why the DispatcherTimer is not IDisposable.

Comment: Had it been any other kind of Timer then a cleanup would have been nice but not essential. The dependency here goes from owned to owner so the GC will resolve it in the end.

Comment: @ℍℍ DispatcherTimer does not implement IDisposable, correct. You don't have to dispose it. Just remove all event handlers from the DispatcherTimer. But Timer for example does implement IDisposable. If resource management wouldn't be an issue, then there won't be an IDisposable interface or using statement/expression. Your argument that a managed resource that references unmanaged resources or ist still a managed resource is weird. Being a managed resource does not mean anything to allocated resources in the first place. Otherwise, there would be no need for IDisposable.

Comment: You still haven't shown a memory leak. Just normal memory usage. The rest is just in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to tell if your application suffers from memory leaks. Only a profiler can tell. At least the code you have posted introduces a memory leak.

Actually, the code introduces two timer related memory leaks.

The first memory leak of the rendered scenario is a classic event handler leak. The special case here is that the timer instance (the event publisher or event source) is kept alive *whenever* a reference to a listener exists (registered event handler). In other words, closing or disposing the `Window` alone will not free the allocated system resource (as this is usually the case with other resources that are allocated using the memory of the current process).
And because the timer is kept alive, the event listeners are kept alive as well.

WPF timers use low-level system or OS timers which are unmanaged (that's why some implement `IDisposable` e.g., `System.Threading.PeriodicTimer` or `System.Threading.Timer`).
This unmanaged system resource is kept alive until the disposal of the referencing timer object or this timer object explicitly frees the timer resource e.g., when the `DispatcherTimer` is stopped.
Because the system timer is an unmanaged system resource that is explicitly kept alive by the framework, timer resources are not freed when the referencing object is disposed or has no incoming references.

To avoid this leak, it is crucial to unregister all event handlers (or in case of timers that implement `IDisposable`, `Dispose()` must be called).
Otherwise, the object instance (e.g. a `Window`) and its complete reference graph is kept alive by the event source (e.g. `DispatcherTimer`) - even when there is no strong reference to the object that owns the timer.

That's why we *must* **always unsubscribe from timer events** (and dispose those timers that implement `IDisposable`).
Unsubscribing from events when we no longer need to observe an object is in general common best practice. Had we followed this best practice the memory leak would have been avoided.

The documentation for the `DispatcherTimer` states:

> *"A DispatcherTimer will keep an object alive whenever the object's methods are bound to the timer."*

Such a bound method is an event handler. For example, in a `Window`, simply override the `Window.OnClosed` method and unregister all event handlers and stop and dispose all timers.

The second memory leak is introduced by missing to stop the `DispatcherTimer`.
In this context, it's also important to note that the `DispatcherTimer` will continue to execute if it is not stoppped by
one of the following events:

- calling `DispatcherTimer.Stop`
- setting `DispatcherTimer.IsEnabled` to `false`.

This also applies to other timers like the `System.Threading-Timer` etc.
When not stopped, the timer will continue to run even if the owner (e.g. a `Window`) has been garbage collected.

The `DispatcherTimer` is a simple wrapper around the system timer. Internally, the created system timer hooks are stored inside a global table. If the `DispatcherTimer` is not stopped, then the timer hook and it's wrapping `DispatcherTimer` is kept alive and continues to execute until the it is explicitly stopped.

This means this second leak exists even if all event handlers are unregistered and no strong reference to the owning object exists and the owner already got garbage collected as the timer continues to execute.

### Summary

The first leak is keeping the window (or in general the object that owns the timer) and all its outgoing references alive. Unregistering all event handlers prevents this memory leak.

The second leak is the timer instance itself. Although the owner of the timer instance has been successfully garbage collected (because all event handlers were correctly unregistered), the timer continues to execute. This means unregistering event handlers is not enough, although it fixes the bigger leak. Stopping the timer prevents the memory leak.

The fixed for the code posted in the question can look as folowes:

```cs
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timerThatUsesunmanagedSystemResources;

  public Window1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.timerThatUsesunmanagedSystemResources = new DispatcherTimer();
    this.timerThatUsesunmanagedSystemResources.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    this.timerThatUsesunmanagedSystemResources.Tick += OnTick;
    this.timerThatUsesunmanagedSystemResources.Start();
  }

  private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // TODO::Do something
  }
  
  protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e) 
  { 
    base.OnClosed(e);

    this.timerThatUsesunmanagedSystemResources.Stop();

    // Unsubscribe ALL handlers from timer events
    // to avoid the event handler leak
    this.timerThatUsesunmanagedSystemResources.Tick -= OnTick;
  }
}
```

---

To prove the memory leak that is introduced by careless timer handling the following section presents the memory profiling results.
The code that was used for profiling can be found at the end of the section.

## Profiler Results

The profiled application contains a simple main window that shows a second `Window` instance (`MemoryLeakWindow`) that runs a `System.Threading.DispatcherTimer` and a `System.Threading.Timer`.

### Context

The profiling involves three scenarios:

**Scenario #1:** The `MemoryLeakWindow` closes without unsubscribing its event handlers from the `System.Threading.DispatcherTimer.Tick` event or disposes the `System.Threading.Timer`.

**Scenario #2:** The `MemoryLeakWindow` closes but unsubscribes its event handlers from the `System.Threading.DispatcherTimer.Tick` event or disposes the `System.Threading.Timer`.

**Scenario #3:** The `MemoryLeakWindow` closes and correctly unsubscribes its event handlers from the `System.Threading.DispatcherTimer.Tick` event. But it forgets to stop the timer, which is expected to cause the timer to continue to run after the `MemoryLeakWindow` has been garbage collected.

### Analysis:

The first screenshot shows the retention paths for the `MemoryLeakWindow` of *Scenario #1*, how it is retained by the event handlers that were registered with the `System.Threading.DispatcherTimer` or `System.Threading.Timer`.

Because an event delegate always stores a strong reference to the event target (in this case `MemoryLeakWindow`) in order to invoke the callback, the target instance won't be eligible for garbage collection, if the event publisher's (e.g., `System.Threading.DispatcherTimer` or `System.Threading.Timer`) lifetime exceeds the lifetime of the event listener.

In this case, the `System.Threading.DispatcherTimer` or `System.Threading.Timer` is keeping the `MemoryLeakWindow` alive until there are no more registered event handlers, forced by the strong reference from the event delegate to the delegate's target:

[image]

The second screenshot shows how *Scenario #2* allows the event listener to be successfully garbage collected after the `MemoryLeakWindow` had stopped the timers and unregistered its event handlers properly from the `System.Threading.DispatcherTimer.Tick` event or the `System.Threading.Timer` has been disposed. Therefore, the event handlers (or the event source to be more precise) are no longer creating a retention path:

[image]

*Note: the `MemoryLeakWindow` instance is artificially kept alive by not clearing the strong reference in the `MainWindow` after closing the `MemoryLeakWindow` instance (e.g., by setting the `TimerWindow` instance variable to `null`).

I did this to show that the closed `MemoryLeakWindow` instance itself is no longer retained by the timers, as now visible in the retention path graph (this also does how important it is to properly control object lifetimes and clear instance variables to allow those references to become eligible for garbage collection). The graph shows that `MemoryLeakWindow` is now only kept alive by the `MainWindow` instance.*

The third screenshot shows that how *Scenario #3* is keeping the `DispatcherTimer` alive and that the timer is still running although all event handlers were previously unregistered and no strong reference to the owning object exists and the owner has already been garbage collected. This is because the timer continues to run:

[image]

The profiler shows that the `DispatcherTimer` instance has `DispatcherTimer.IsEnabled` still set to `true`, which means it is still running and consuming memory (second memory leak). Unless we stop the timer, it will run for the lifetime of the application.

### Profiled Context

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private MemoryLeakWindow TimerWindow { get; set; } 

  private void OnShowMemoryLeakWindowClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.TimerWindow = new MemoryLeakWindow();
    this.TimerWindow.Show();
  }

  private void OnCloseMemoryLeakWindowWithoutUnregisterEventHandlersClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.TimerWindow.IsUnregisterEventHandlersEnabled = false;
    this.TimerWindow.Close();

    // Although the strong reference is removed, the MemoryLeakWindow
    // and all its referenced objects are kept alive in memory
    // by the timer.
    this.TimerWindow = null;
  }

  private void OnCloseMemoryLeakWindowAndUnregisterEventHandlersClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.TimerWindow.IsUnregisterEventHandlersEnabled = true;
    this.TimerWindow.Close();

    // Important: to allow the MemoryLeakWindow to get garbage collected
    // we must remove the strong reference 
    // e.g., by setting the instance or class variable to null.
    // This example is not doing this in order to keep the instance alive 
    // so that we can check with the memory profiler that the retention path of the timer is now removed.
    // The following line is deliberately not executed
    // for scenario #1 + #2. but executed for scenario #3
    //this.TimerWindow = null;
  }
}
```

**MemoryLeakWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MemoryLeakWindow : Window
{
  public bool IsUnregisterEventHandlersEnabled { get; set; }
  private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
  private Timer timer;

  public MemoryLeakWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer(
      TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
      DispatcherPriority.Input,
      OnDispatcherTimerTicked,
      Application.Current.Dispatcher);

    this.timer = new Timer(
      OnTimerTicked,
      null,
      TimeSpan.Zero,
      TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
  }

  protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnClosed(e);

    if (this.IsUnregisterEventHandlersEnabled)
    {
      // If not stopped, the timer instance will leak
      // as it will continue to run
      this.dispatcherTimer.Stop();

      // If not unregistered, the event handlers will keep the MemoryLeakWindow alive
      this.dispatcherTimer.Tick -= OnDispatcherTimerTicked;

      // If not stopped, the event handlers will keep the MemoryLeakWindow alive
      _ = this.timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);

      // If not disposed, the timer instance will leak
      this.timer.Dispose();
    }
  }

  private void OnTimerTicked(object? state)
  {
    this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
      double currentProgressValue = this.TimerProgressBar.Value;
      this.TimerProgressBar.Value = currentProgressValue >= 60 
        ? 1 
        : currentProgressValue + 1;
    }, DispatcherPriority.Input);
  }

  private void OnDispatcherTimerTicked(object? sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    double currentProgressValue = this.DispatcherTimerProgressBar.Value;
    this.DispatcherTimerProgressBar.Value = currentProgressValue >= 60 
      ? 1 
      : currentProgressValue + 1;
  }
}
```

**MemoryLeakWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="Net.Wpf.MemoryLeakWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Net.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MemoryLeakWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <StackPanel>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="DispatcherTimerProgressBar"
                 Maximum="60" />
    <ProgressBar x:Name="TimerProgressBar"
                 Maximum="60"
                 Foreground="Blue" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: You resuls only show that when you use the  OnClose then,  yes the references go away. They do not show anything close to a memoryleak. And apparently the MainWindow still holds a reference to the LeakWindow, making it all rather moot.

Comment: @ℍℍ Not sure why objects that are not collected during the lifetime of the application are not a memory leak. You must have a wrong understanding of a memory leak in a managed memory model.

Comment: This is getting long. Use scenario #1, ie leave the eventhandlers, and clean all references from MainWindow etc. Then run GC.Collect() and show me where the LeakWindow is still kept alive.

Comment: @HH The MainWindow is a branch of the retention graph because of the strong reference. If I set the variable or the strong reference to NULL, then the MainWindow disappears from the graph. Still the two timers remain as they continue to prevent the instance from being garbage collected. I have posted the complete profiling context. You can run it and play around with it yourself. It's really sad that we can't have a real discussion.

Comment: Turns out you're right about the DispatcherTimer, it is just that you code here doesn't prove it, i had to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25510873/60761) first.  And it's not the kind of leak the OP was talking about.

Comment: @ℍℍ At least you came back to admit that you were wrong about the timer. I really appreciate that; I wasn't expecting that. We don't know what the OP was talking about. He actually showed an empty Tick handler. His code produces a memory leak and I have pointed that out. So, for me the usage of the DispatcherTImer is the only cause for a leak I can find in his code. Indeed, stopping the timer will also avoid the leak. Your latest post was valuable and adds good additional information to the topic. I hope we can start our discussion like that next time instead of the unnecessary rudeness.

Comment: @BionicCode The OP was asking about a memory leak while the program was running. It seems to me that you have proved that a memory leak occurs when the program is closed. An important point that I hadn't thought to worry about

Comment: @ℍℍ If his window is a secondary application screen like a dialog etc. or a window in a multi-screen application then the leak occurs early on and frequently, keeping each such window instance and its complete reference tree alive. So this is a potentially huge leak. He only showed how he set up the timer and an empty tick handler. I'm just saying that this isn't the best question. If he was not talking about the timer leak then the question is just bad.

Comment: As others have pointed out you didn't understand the question. The supposed "memory leak" was not because of the event handler because they're not even talking about after it's closed. The GC isn't going to immediately run every single second when that `Text` is updated. You spent all this time on this post and didn't stop and think about what they were actually asking. P.S. Using `WeakEventManager` is a better irrelevant solution if you're gonna go this route.

Comment: @Trey The code of posted by the OP does create two timer related leaks. I'm not stupid. If the window in the OP's example is a dialog or some other window that is showed frequently, he doesn't have to wait until the window is closed. A leak is a leak. The more often the window is instantiated the more memory will leak. This is all anybody can say because there is not more information. We can't tell what else is causing a leak or what else is not a leak. It's all assumptions and speculations. I hope you understand this. The only fact here is the leak introduced by the timer handling.

Comment: @Trey Using the `WeakEventManager` or any other weak event pattern implementation is not a *better* solution. It's a different solution, preferably used when you can't control or guarantee to unsubscribe from events.

Comment: @ℍℍ Just for the sake of completeness. There are actually two memory leaks: #1  prevents the owner of the timer from being garbage collected and #2 prevents the timer itself from being garbage collected. Solution for #1 is to unregister all event handlers and #2 is to stop the still running timer.

Comment: @BionicCode The posted code is a complete application. The window never closes, the app never quits, and yet the memory usage appears to increase constantly. The question is asking why. If the window did close then you are right that a memory leak would occur, but that would not happen in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be a memory leak in your codes. The memory increases just because of the GC.Collect() method is not called at real-time.

Try this:

```
void StaticTick(object o, EventArgs sender)
{
    GC.Collect();
    memoryuseage.Text = GC.GetTotalMemory(true).ToString();
}
```

Comment: It is almost always a bad idea to call GC.Collect(), and it very often won't really do what you think it will. For example: references may exist you don't realize, meaning you will end up promoting objects to higher generations, causing them to stay in memory longer.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Not sure if you noticed but this is to quickly test this. It isn't a business critical application in production that is being updated. You can also specify which generation you want to collect, and there are other options like specifying the `GCCollectionMode`. On top of that, you're basing this on "may exist", "you don't realize", and "won't really do what you think it will."

Comment: @Trey We don't have any context. We don't know if this is a business application or whatever. It also doesn't matter as this is just a general recommendation. He  wrote *"almost always"*. This allows for exceptions. He also used *"very often"* which correctly describes the unpredictable behavior of the garbage collector. It's a very sophisticated algorithm. Garbage collection actually uses application resources. It's expensive and heavy. That's the reason for the garbage collector to run periodically (controlled by the algorithm) and not constantly.

Comment: @Trey It's absolutely correct and important to give advice not to manually interfere with the GC. C# has finalizers and encourages the dispose pattern. That's enough client level control (for the sake of runtime environment performance). You are free to use `GC.Collect` where and how often you want. But  it's absolutely correct to point out that this comes with risks and costs. The comment that you critisize does that well enough.