# Unreferenced active DispatcherTimer and garbage collector

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, garbage-collection

I have the following XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label Name="lblTime" FontSize="48" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind is :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
        GC.Collect();
    }
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Some facts I know :

- Even though .NET garbage collector is a nondeterministic one, the collection can be forced by the call of GC.Collect()
- When collection is being done, any unreferenced object is destroyed

In the code-behind, MainWindow doesn't hold any reference to the timer. In my mind, it should be destroyed and the interface should not be updated anymore, since I put some GC.Collect calls. But it seems it doesn't work since the interface is still being updated, and therefore, the object is still alive.

The question is : what is going on ? Am I wrong somewhere ? Or did I miss some important fact ?

**Edit 1** : this code is actually an exemple I found in an tutorial, displaying how to use DispatcherTimer. But I wondered what would happen when the garbage collection would start, that's why I added those GC.Collect in order to see what would happen. Thanks to the good amount of tutorials about .NET GC I have read, I know that calling GC.Collect is a bad idea, and should not be done, unless very exceptional cases.

Comment: DispatcherTimer takes special measures to stay alive. It cheats.

Comment: I think (though I'm not sure) subscribing to an event can stop GC, not sure on the details but I'd investigate GC with events.

Comment: I hope this is just experimental code & not an actual application intended for production use.  Calling `GC.Collect()` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Dispatcher class maintains an internal `List<DispatcherTimer>` for active timers.  The internal [Dispatcher.AddTimer()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs#2759) method adds it, called on the Start() method.  RemoveTimer() is called by the Stop() method.

That keeps the GC seeing a reference, until you stop the timer.  Which you can only do in the event handler by casting the *sender* argument, only way to get the reference back yourself.

Do keep in mind that it *does* keep ticking if you don't call Stop(), even if a Window that has an event handler for the timer is closed.  Such a window object will leak if you don't, you'll get an ObjectDisposedException only if you're lucky.

Comment: The potential for a leak is extremely important to handle & not something I knew about until this post.  Gotta watch out for that!